# Should I write YARN application hadoop 2.6.0?

Tags: api, hadoop, mapreduce, version, hadoop-yarn

I want to use hadoop 2.6.0 and by default it's on YARN mode. So should I write the YARN application like this :

http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/WritingYarnApplications.html

Or I'm just write some mapreduce application like usual? And what the function of this YARN application?

I nned your suggest, Thanks all.....

Answer (score 0):

Think of YARN as data operating system & MapReduce as your application which runs on top of YARN.

So, you existing MapReduce code should work without any modifications even on YARN mode.

The code example you have posted shows how you could develop your own applications on top of YARN which hides the abstractions of resource allocation, multi-tenancy, distributed programming, failover and so on. For example MapReduce framework itself is re-written as YARN application so that it could run on top of YARN. This allows YARN to run multiple applications (MapReduce, Spark, Tez, Storm, etc) simultaneously on the same cluster.

Comment: oooooo thanks bro for your comment, now I'm little bit know about YARN. So in your opinion, which faster YARN (hadoop 2) or classic (hadoop 1) on the same mapreduce job.

Once again thanks....

Comment: As YARN does not improve existing MapReduce, but will enable other MR implementations to be better in all aspects. So YARN will not speed up the existing MapReduce.

Comment: Ooooo bro sorry I want to ask again hahaha sory
if you know on mapred-site.xml there is a configuration about mapreduce.framework.name, If I write that configuration with "YARN" as values. It's make my mapreduce process become slower than before.

Thanks a lot bro....

Comment: In your oppinion, how many minimum computer can run the hadoop mode YARN? thanks....